# Getting bills even though i was told im paid up

Tags: billing

I had a roofing company setup a temporary fix when my roof was leaking. When I finally got the bill I called them to pay it. I thought it seemed a little low but they told me that's all I owed and now I'm good.

Later on I started second guessing it (the bill was hard to understand), called them up a couple days later and asked if I still owe anything else and I was told no, that everything has been paid.

About a month later I get a call from them asking for payment. I told them they said I paid everything already. They said they would look into it and let me know. Didn't get a call back until...

Another month later, I have another bill sitting in my mailbox.

At this point I don't know if I owe more or not. Should I keep saying I already paid it because that's what they told me, twice? Or am I going to be stuck paying this again? What if it goes to collections?

**UPDATE - More details**

Okay so I looked back at all the papers I got from them and I see what I was missing.. I originally got two bills with a separate paper defining what each charge was for. At that time I was still waiting for home insurance to take care of it (which they ended up not) so I didn't look at it too closely. I don't know why they put the services on two invoices but they did (two invoice numbers).

So when I got the bills a second time I was confused on why the two bills with similar charges ($460 and $540). I called them to pay it expecting to pay both, they charged me for the $540 bill and I asked if that was it, they said that was all.

A few days later I start to question it again just thinking back to the two bills and getting worried I still owe them. So I called them back and asked again if I owe them any more. Again, they said I'm all paid up.

A while later I get that emailed PDF saying the $540 bill is paid. And then even later I get the phone call asking for payment (I think for the $460 amount) and I tell them I paid them and forwarded them that email back. They said they would look into it, and haven't heard anything back until now when I get another bill in the mail for the $540 one.

I'm going to head up to their office today and talk it out in person. I'm sure I'll end up having to pay the other one, but is very frustrating that they said I was paid up on two separate times and yet this...

Comment: Can you get something in writing from them that confirms you're paid up? It sounds like you're calling and getting a verbal confirmation, but unless you get it in writing, they could start saying you're overdue. Sometimes it's a case of the left hand not know what the right is doing/saying when it comes to the Accounting Dept and Customer Service, even at small companies.

Comment: I did get an email from them at one point with a pdf of the bill with a paid stamp on it.

Comment: Does the most recent bill match the amount that you paid? If it's different, then you should call and ask about the specific amount. Any invoice numbers or anything to match it on? There's also the chance that you're being sent someone else's bill by accident. Clerical errors happen all the time, and it may be that you're account is paid up and they're trying to send a bill to someone entirely different but screwing up the address.

Comment: Add more details to an update in original post. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up going to their office in person and talking to them. Sounds like their accountant was on maternity leave and the person filling in messed up. They weren't entirely sure what was wrong either so they just wrote off the other bill. So all good after all!!